# Titanium Android retrieve intent extras through notification

Tags: titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

I have a background service that I start as soon as the app is lunched. This background service asks to the server every 5 seconds if there are new data available, as soon as there are new data I create a notification. When I click the notification app is lunched, but I am not able to retrieve the intent extra parameters that I put when I create the notification.

Below the code:
index.js

```
 startService();

 function startService(){ 
    if(OS_ANDROID){  
       log("START SERVICE");
       var intent = Titanium.Android.createServiceIntent({
       url: 'service.js'
    });
    Titanium.Android.startService(intent);
    }
  }





//===========================================
// I tried to add this code so that I could get the intent but it does not work

if(OS_ANDROID){


    log("==========================" + JSON.stringify(Ti.Android.currentActivity));
      // prints : {"bubbleParent":true,"actionBar":{"navigationMode":0,"bubbleParent":true,"title":null,"apiName":"Ti.Android.ActionBar"},"apiName":"Ti.Android.Activity"}



    var _intent = Ti.Android.currentActivity.getIntent();
    log(JSON.stringify(_intent));
    //prints {"bubbleParent":true,"action":null,"type":null,"data":null,"flags":268435456,"apiName":"Ti.Android.Intent"}



    if (_intent.hasExtra('ntfId')) {
       log("========= INTENT HAS EXTRA =========");
    }else{
       log("========= NO INTENT HAS EXTRA =========");
    }


    var currActivity = Titanium.Android.currentActivity;
    var passedInText = currActivity.getIntent().getStringExtra(Ti.Android.EXTRA_TEXT);
    log(passedInText);
     //prints null

}
```

service.js

```
function createNotification(data){
log(data.id + " <<<<<<>>>>>> " + data.type);
var activity = Ti.Android.currentActivity;
var intent = Ti.Android.createIntent({ 
    className : 'packageName.AppNameActivity',
    action: Ti.Android.ACTION_MAIN,
    packageName: Ti.App.id,
    flags: Ti.Android.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Ti.Android.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
});
intent.addCategory(Titanium.Android.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER); 

intent.putExtra("ntfId", data.id);

var pending = Ti.Android.createPendingIntent({ 
    intent : intent
});

var notification = Ti.Android.createNotification({
    contentIntent : pending,
    contentTitle : data.title,
    contentText : data.desription,
    tickerText : "AppName",
    icon : Ti.App.Android.R.drawable.appicon,
    sound: 'default',
    defaults: Titanium.Android.NotificationManager.DEFAULT_VIBRATE,
    flags : Titanium.Android.ACTION_DEFAULT | Titanium.Android.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL | Titanium.Android.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS
});



Ti.Android.NotificationManager.notify(data.notification_id, notification);
}
```

I want to get "ntfId" when my app opens, so I can know which notification I clicked and show the correct data.

What I have found so far with the notifications is just how to lunch the application, and that does work but there is no clear example how to get notification detail. 
I followed this [link](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/Android+Notifications#AndroidNotifications-IfweusetheclassNameproperty:) and [docs](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Android_Notifications) , but I'm using Alloy model.

In case it is useful, I'll add my TiApp.xml too:

```
    <android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <manifest>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
        <application android:debuggable="true">
            <activity
                android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
                android:name="org.appcelerator.titanium.TiActivity" 
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
            <activity
                android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
                android:label="Appname"
                android:launchMode="singleTask"
                android:name=".AppnameActivity"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@style/Theme.Titanium">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        </application>
    </manifest>
    <services>
        <service url="service.js"/>
    </services>
</android>
```

How do I get the extra parameters passed from the notification intent? Seems like when I do getCurrentActivity.getIntent() it's another intent totally different from what I want to get.

Can you suggest me something or point somewhere that maybe I missed looking at?
Thanks!

**Last Edit**
I pushed my project on gihub, [TiAndroidNotification](https://github.com/linnal/TiAndroidNotification) you can clone it and try, and see if you can change something.. It's not working yet, I'm still working on trying to solve this problem..
Thanks for any help or feedback!

Answer (score 1):

I figure half of it out.
When the pending intent is created we should add even the activity:

```
var activity = Ti.Android.currentActivity;
var pending = Ti.Android.createPendingIntent({ 
    activity:activity,
    intent : intent
});
```

and from index.js I get it like this:

```
var act = Titanium.Android.currentActivity;
var _intent = act.intent;
var message = _intent.getStringExtra("ntfId");
```

This works ok as long as I close the application, but if the application is just in background and I click the notification it passes null and I do not understand why..

Comment: Can you please show your final code, if you have it working. Even I'm stuck with the same problem. Application opens but i get NULL value with getStringExtra function

Comment: I'm still working on this.. I do not have a solution yet

Answer (score 0):

i've replaced the flags with  Ti.Android.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Ti.Android.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK and it's working perfectly. It restarts the app, but it works.

and also you forgot to add "type : Titanium.Android.PENDING_INTENT_FOR_ACTIVITY" to pending.

Comment: Hello @mihai-blaga, I tried it but it stops in the splash screen. I created a github project, if you have time you can try it and make the modifications you want and let me know :) [github_project](https://github.com/linnal/TiAndroidNotification)

Answer (score 0):

here the js module I'm using

https://gist.github.com/muka/d4afae20a5732f3937e8

Seems responding properly when app is in background or foreground

Basically, the main activity listen to the `newintent` event and look for expected data in the intent extras received as argument

I'm curious to see if it works for different use cases, let me know.

Thanks